# Fleis' Kappa statistic indicates very limited agreement between testers but ANOVA test shows very little difference between means

Tags: anova, agreement-statistics

I have been asked to help a friend complete a statistics assigment for a non-statistics course.  Disclaimer:  I am not performing the work, and am merely going to explain to them how to perform the work themselves.

The test they have been assigned is to conduct an ANOVA test on the testing results of different participants in a testing trial.  Each particpant rates different attribute data of the group on a one-to-five score. THe dataset is as follows (characteristics have been changed to random adjectives from the dictionary):

[image]

The student has been asked by the professor to conduct an ANOVA test to identify whether there is a statistically significant differente between the mean values of the characteristics chosen by each tester. The output of an ANOVA test for this is:

```
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
            group       10   5.53  0.5526   0.378  0.952
            Residuals   66  96.43  1.4610
```

This indicates that the mean values are not different by a statistically significant amount.

However, I don't think this is a valid example of what is basically an Attribute Agreement Test, so I calculated Fleiss' Kappa, with these results:

```
 Subjects = 7 
 Raters = 11 
 Kappa = 0.0575 

    z = 2.95 
  p-value = 0.00314 

 Kappa      z p.value
 0   -0.013 -0.258   0.796
 0.5  0.029  0.566   0.572
 1    0.060  1.179   0.238
 1.5  0.029  0.566   0.572
 2   -0.032 -0.633   0.527
 2.5  0.109  2.141   0.032
 3    0.064  1.250   0.211
 3.5 -0.018 -0.357   0.721
 4    0.107  2.104   0.035
 4.5  0.076  1.491   0.136
 5    0.187  3.674   0.000
```

To me, the Kappa test indicates a very low level of agreement among the testers.

If the professor is right, and ANVOA is a valid attribute agreement test for this purpose, then the Kappa statistic must be wrong.  But I don't think it is, and that there is no relationship between the mean value of multiple different characteristics chosen by different testers, and any measure of reproducability across testers.

Is the professor right, or am I?

And have I conducted the Fleissman's Kappa test properly?  I'm not sure as I'm not used to working in R.

This is a very time-sensitive query and help would be appreciated.